# Firebase hosting changes an element's opacity to 1% whenever it has CSS opacity

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, firebase-hosting

I'm developing a website with Vue.js and Firebase. Locally, everything works correctly and a button I intend to have low opacity works fine. Whenever I deploy to Firebase Hosting, that button changes its opacity to 1% and so becomes invisible. I have to remove any opacity CSS for it to work, as anything will automatically lower to 1%. As I said, only happens in the hosting whereas locally it works as intended. Any ideas what could be happening?
I have built and deployed several times to solve any build errors that could have been happening.

Comment: Need to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Hi. I didn't add anything because it is a single line of CSS. It is just setting the opacity of a button, nothing else. Thanks for the correction, if it is necessary I will add it no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a common problem people run across when [using Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/numbers).

> Percentages in Sass work just like every other unit. They are not
> interchangeable with decimals, because in CSS decimals and percentages
> mean different things. For example, 50% is a number with % as its
> unit, and Sass considers it different than the number 0.5.

Instead of using percentages in your CSS, change them to the equivalent decimal representation.

For example, use `opacity: 0.8;` instead of `opacity: 80%;`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try doing this. Any idea why it would give me this problem now if I've been using percentages throughout the whole project?

Comment: Not sure, sometimes with javascript frameworks it depends on if it's component specific CSS, but hard to say exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot your suggestion worked! Still not sure why this button caused problems when everything else is mostly in percentages, but it's working now.